# Timing of MPI program changes dramatically after submitting to the queue

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, sungridengine, qsub

I have a MPI program that create a file which have time per iteration of certain amount of calculations. When I run this code without submitting to the queue(this cluster runs SGE), it gives following time in seconds. I grabbed 8 processors using `mpirun -np8`.

```
STEP    ITIME     
-------------
 1  0.868128 
 2  0.426714 
 3  0.409768 
 4  0.427312 
 5  0.412737 
 6  0.413256 
 7  0.414480 
 8  0.414984 
 9  0.415683 
10  0.416826
```

But when I submit the same amount of work for 8 processors and submit it to the queue, the program take more time for calculation of the iterations. The time per step is almost four times.

```
STEP    ITIME    
-------------
 1  3.189155  
 2  1.594365  
 3  1.600892  
 4  1.589424  
 5  1.605402  
 6  1.589136  
 7  1.599425  
 8  1.591966  
 9  1.601557 
10  1.603447
```

The following bash script was used to submit the job.

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -pe orte 8
export PATH=~:$PATH
/opt/openmpi/bin/mpirun -np 8 ./exec
```

I will appreciate if someone can point me out what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first case (run this code without submitting to the queue), you are probably running 8 processes on the same node.  That's usually fine nowadays: you've likely got 8 cores.

Try this out:

```
$ /opt/openmpi/bin/mpirun -np 8 uname -a
```

did you get 8 identical lines?

In the SGE case, you might get 8 physical machines, so now there is network communication involved.  Confirm as above.  I don't know SGE, but your environment no doubt has a "how to assign mpi processes" switch to indicate if you want it to assigndepth first or breadth first.

Comment: I tried $ /opt/openmpi/bin/mpirun -np 8 uname -a. When I run it on the command line I got 8 identical lines. But, when I try it submitting to the queue I got 8 different lines. Seems like it ran on 8 different hosts.

Comment: well there you go:  your command line is executing on one machine, and processes are exchanging messages through either shared memory or very fast local loopback.   your queue submission requested 8 nodes and ran over those 8 nodes.  nothing wrong with that -- you might scale out to a higher level of parallelism that way -- but that's what's going on.